# Autodesk User Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am trying to automatize our cloud licenses assignment and permissions and I've done good progress with Office 365 and BIM 360 (for the permission per project part).

We are now planning to roll-out BIM 360 Design to many users (100+) and with  our current 15 licenses, it's already quite complicated to manage assignment via Autodesk CEP panel. Thus, I'm trying to find informations on an API that could be used to manage users license assigment, similar to what we can do here: https://manage.autodesk.com/cep/#user-management

If assignment cannot be changed via an API, a report with current assignments could be a good start so I can have some reconciliation done on the side...

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [BIM 360 APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/) that are now publicly available focus on the management of project users. There's no endpoint for licensing purposes at the moment.

For assignment reporting or other BIM360 Design issues please visit our [forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-design-collaboration/bd-p/6011) - questions on SO is not attended to by the relevant teams.